# Pass value of <h4>tag from one aspx page to another aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using an anchor tag in one aspx page to redirect to another aspx page .But I need to pass value of particluar h4 also from source to destination page so that I can display it on header .

**first page.aspx**

```
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12" runat="server" id="line_1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header position-relative">
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left; width: 75%">
                                <h4 class="mb-0 ml-4 line_name" id="line_name_1">Place1Line</h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <a href="LinePage.aspx" class="stretched-link"></a>
                </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12" runat="server" id="line_2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header position-relative">
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left; width: 75%">
                                <h4 class="mb-0 ml-4 line_name" id="line_name_2">Place2Line</h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <a href="LinePage.aspx" class="stretched-link"></a>
                </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

**LinePage.aspx**

```
     <div id="header1" class="float-left ml-4">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" Class="label_header" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
     </div>
```

I need h4 tag value of id **line_name_1** if anchor tag of **id="line_1" card**  is clicked. similarily, h4 value of **line_name_2**  if anchor tag of l**ine_2 card** is clicked .
which is to be displayed in Text="" of asp_label control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add query strings into your anchor tags:

```html
<a href="LinePage.aspx?text=TheTextToTransfer" id="line_1">YourLinkText</a>
```

(In the second anchor change the query.) Then access query data in your code-behind:

```cs
string text = Request.QueryString["text"];
```

And assign the value of `text` as the value in your label in `LinePage.aspx`.

Comment: Thanks !! I didn't knew about usage of query strings in anchor tag !